# Packaging and installing media items not working - items are created but have no attached file

Tags: media-library, installation, packages

My content authors uploaded a ton of media items in our UAT environment. I'm trying to package these and install in prod, but the installation isn't working. I'm created a regular Sitecore package with the Installation wizard, selected the root folder of all of the new media items (with subitems) and created the package. When I install in prod, all of the media items are created but have no attached image. I tried installing several times and overwriting all items but I can't get it to work.

UAT:
[image]

Prod:
[image]

Comment: You should perform an item package of the media you want to install on production together with a file package where you add the images. From the screenshot, it seems that your media are being stored in the `App_Data/Replicated/MediaFiles/...`

Answer (score 4):

I can't be sure from your incomplete screenshots, but from the bit of the "File Path" field showing in your Prod screenshot, I guess your media items are using File storage rather than Database storage. I don't believe Sitecore will manage copying your actual storage files from UAT to Prod for you; you will have to do that as a separate step. I guess that the missing storage files in Prod is why you don't see a rendering of the media item in the Media field.

Comment: Thank you - I wasn't familiar with the File Storage option.

Answer (score 2):

According to me you are trying to create package of media item for which actual media is stored in file system so I will say follow below steps to create you package.

1. Go to Package Designer.
2. Then you can go to Items statically.
3. Then select the media items and other related items of your requirement.

[image]

4. Now for the images/media from file system you need to go Files statically.
5. Then you will get you file root where ideally your media should be places.
6. Then you can select all media from from the folder where it is.

[image]

And now you are good for installing this package for Production.